# For a given complex number $z$, how many complex $x$ exist satisfying $x^n=z$ for real noninteger $n$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, complex-numbers

I have no idea if this problem even has a general solution. In fact, I'm pretty much convinced it doesn't, at least for irrational $n$. But if it does, please provide an explanation.

Comment: Take a look at roots of unity.  For complex z, we just dilate the roots of unity by the the nth root of the magnitude and rotate them by the angle that z forms.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is, what you mean by $x^n$ if $n$ is a non-integer and $x$ a complex number?

One approach is to say that $x^n$ is a multivalued function, i.e $x^n = e^{n \log x}$ where $\log x$ is any branch of the logarithm.  If so,
the solutions of $x^n = z$ (i.e. all $x$ such that any branch of $x^n$ is $z$) are $x = z^{1/n} = \exp({1/n \log z}$ for any branch of $\log z$.  If $n$ is irrational, there are infinitely many of those.

Another approach is to pick just one branch of $x^n$, e.g. the principal branch: $x^n = e^{n \text{Log}(x)}$, where $\text{Log}(x)$ is the branch of $\log x$ with imaginary part in the interval $(-\pi, \pi]$.  Then there are
at most $\lceil n \rceil$ solutions.